# Increment subdocument matching specific requirements on mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

## Context

- mongodb 4.0
- mongoose ODM 5.4.15

## Question

I would like to increment nested subdocuments that match specific given requirements using `update` function.

Here is a raw example document i will update :

```
{
    _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef83,
    subdocuments :[{
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef84,
        position: 3,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef85,
        position: 0,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef86,
        position: 2,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef87,
        position: 1,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef88,
        position: 4,
    }]
}
```

I would like to `$inc` elements into the `subdocuments` array that have a position `$gte` than **2**.

After the update, the given document should become :

```
{
    _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef83,
    subdocuments :[{
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef84,
        position: **4**,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef85,
        position: 0,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef86,
        position: **3**,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef87,
        position: 1,
    }, {
        _id: 5c73fba86cd17000576eef88,
        position: **5**,
    }]
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try somethings like that:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: docId, 
    'subdocuments.position': { $gte: 2},
  }, { 
    $inc : {'subdocuments.$.position': 1}
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this query will find all documents that have a `subdocuments.position` greater than 2, and then increment **each** subdocuments position of each document, which i **do not want to do**. I want to increment **only subdocuments that have a positon greater than 2**.

Comment: Did you try it ? I use this kind of query to update nested objects and that work perfectly. As the default behaviours for mongoose query is an AND. So to be updated the subdocument need to be in the main document with the id "docId" AND be greater than 2

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me to understand.